# AJAX not working with Django App

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-templates

**mysite/urls.py**:

```
from mysite import views

url(r'^checkhandles/$', views.checkhandles, name='checkhandles'),
```

**mysite/views.py**:

```
def checkhandles(request, email):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = 'Yes, I am reachable!'
    else:
        message = 'No, I am not reachable!'
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

**mysite-ajax.js**: on DOM-ready.

```
$(document).on('blur', '#email', function(){
    var $this = $( this );
    var email = $this.val();
    if (validateEmail(email) === true){
    alert(email);
        var request = $.ajax({
          url: "/mysite/checkhandles/",
          type: "POST",
          data: { email : email },
          dataType: "json"
        });
        request.done(function( msg ) {
            alert( msg );
            //$(".email_details").html( msg ); 
            //$(".email_etails").slideDown(150);
        });
    };
})
```

How do I this work? It only `alert(email)` and `alert(msg)` that can tell that can tell AJAX was successful doesn't work.

Comment: How do you make *what* work? What isn't currently working? What does "nothing happens henceforth" mean? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @DanielRoseman `alert(msg)` doesn't pop up which shows that my AJAX isn't working and I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: What do you see in the Django console? What about in the browser dev tools console? Have you tried adding a `fail` handler to the Ajax object?

Comment: It doesn't show anything. When I Tab, it simply goes to the next textbox. Let me add `fail` and see.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I have tried `request.fail(function(){alert('AJAX fail to load your content');})` and it alerts `AJAX fail to load your content`. What do I do?

Comment: please debug the error message. request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){...}). documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @chfw: `textStatus` says `error` while `errorThrown` say `FORBIDDEN`.

Comment: @Yax, so it means ajax cannot access your link, 403 Forbidden. Use your browser, can you access .../mysite/checkhandles/ at all?

Comment: @chfw: Yes it is reachable. I just tried it but the AJAX call still return FORBIDDEN.

Comment: please provide exact error you are facing, it will be helpful. In this case you may be facing HTTP(403) forbidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a CSRF token problem. Do you send the `csrftoken` cookie ?  Go there https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-ajax to understand what appends and copy/paste this javascript code from Django web site :

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```