# Pass arguments to a django template using AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-tables2

I am new with Django and JavaScript and I am struggling trying to pass some values from a html table rendered with django-tables2

I want to open a django template passing 3 arguments. 
I have an html table with a drop down button with several options. 
every open a different django template. I get the values from the table with this JS function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function param(){
 $(function(){
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var rows = tbl.rows;
  var url = "/recepcion/";
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
   rows[i].onclick =  function(){
   idpro = this.cells;
   ano = this.cells;
   mes1 = this.cells;
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "/recepcion/",
    datatype: "json",
    data: ({idprov: idpro[0].innerHTML, anio: ano[1].innerHTML, mes: mes1[2].innerHTML }),
    success: function(){
      http.open("POST",url,true),
      http.send(data)
        }
  });
   }
  }
 });
}
</script>
```

The functionality that i need is: When I click in the first option of the drop down button call this function. The function will take the value from some cells and pass this values as arguments to another template where i can edit some record.
This is the view where I try to pass the arguments
views.py

```
def RecepcionView(request):
    idp = request.POST.get('idpro')
    year = request.POST.get('year')
    month = request.POST.get('month')
    if request.method == 'POST':
       r = DetalleRecepcion.objects.get(id_proveedor=idp,year=year,month=month)
       form = RecepcionForm(request.POST, instance=r)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/monitor/')
    else:
       r = DetalleRecepcion.objects.get(id_proveedor=idp,year=year,month=month)
       form = RecepcionForm(instance=r)
    return render_to_response('recepcion.html',
                              {'form':form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**UPDATE**
I change the function and I put all inside a function and now can I pass the arguments, but I get the error:

**ReferenceError: data is not defined**

**http.send(data)**

In firebug I can see the function pass the value to the view and the view answer the form with the info that I need, but I need to open the form not only pass the value.

**Any advice.**

Comment: what (atleast, do you think) `idpro` is ? There is no reference to the variable in the code you have shown. May be that is a good place to start debugging

Comment: I am trying to pass the values from the javascript function "param" to the ajax request, but doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, but would be very hard to help you if you dont know exactly what you need to achieve, what exactly is not working, and pointing to the relevant flow of code.

Comment: @karthikr thanks for the replies. I update the question and paste all the ajax function and the django view where I try to pass the argument. The view receive three arguments and render a form where I can edit the records. Thanks in advance

Comment: NOoo. please dont paste everything. Only the relevant parts of code..

Comment: Don't worry When i say I past all I mean only the function that I need to fix. You can see that I try to get the value from some specific cells and after pass as arguments. The error is when I try to pass and open the another page which is a simple django form

Comment: First of all, you have not declared url anywhere. The mapping's key is not automatically assigned to a local variable. So, explicitly declare a local variable url and initialize it to the desired url. Second, you have enclosed the entire jquery code inside a function, and not calling it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I followed and I changed the order of my function and apparently works but now I get the error: ReferenceError: data is not defined http.send(data). In firebug I can see the function work passing the values but the form where I pass the values won't open. Thanks again

Comment: @joseleg it is because the ``data`` isnot known inside ``success`` function. you should define it before ``$.ajax`` and refer to it inside success function

Comment: Before you proceed with the more complicated stuff, i would recommend you getting some basic (hardcoded) stuff working. You are almost there - just getting confused with the syntax, etc.. One you have that, extend it to programmatically feed the `data`

Comment: You may want to have a lot at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868726/ajax-not-working-with-django-app/25873201#25873201